# Is Gcc 4.8.1 RELEASE available under raring 13.04 ? ( no snapshot, only release )

Tags: gcc, c++, g++

I need full c++11 support and I need gcc 4.8.1 release, I'm under Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit, there is a `gcc-snapshot` package in the repository, but it's outdated and it's an old pre-release version.

It's possible to get an official support for the 4.8.1 ? It's hidden somewhere in the repository ?

please no PPA.

Comment: Official support?  What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

It would be rather difficult for a distribution [released in April](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2013-April/000171.html) to have "official support" for a compiler [released on the last day of May](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-announce/2013/msg00004.html).

Comment: and how this is related to my question ? delete your answer.

Comment: Obviously @user2485710, you weren't born yesterday, you were born tomorrow. Thanks for pointing out the error.